# Communicating with fragment from Menu and updating the fragment UI?

Tags: android, fragment

I am trying to implement a fairly basic UI.

I have an Activity and within it a Fragment that does an HTTP Get and updates some values in the fragment.

This works fine, now I would like to have a menu to refresh this - the menu is contained within the Activity.

The problem I have is I am unsure about how to handle the method calls. Basically I have found that getActivity() within the fragment returns null when I am updating it from my menu handler.

So I have this bit of code in the Activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        handler = new GetData();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("FFF", "Exception: " + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }

}
```

GetData() is my activity java class

Now in my onOptionsItemSelect event if I use the handler from above (making handler a global var) it works but getActivity() is null in the fragment.

Using the code below returns null when called in the onOptionsItemSelected Event

```
GetData handler = (GetData) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.verticalwetherlayout);
```

Is there a tutorial that explains this part? or maybe I am just doing things wrong?

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.

I was using the actual ID of the fragment not the ID of the instance of the fragment defined in the activity.

so the id of the fragment was R.layout.verticalwetherlayout

but the actual Id of the fragment in the activity was GetData1

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/GetData1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.example.testapp1.GetData" />
```

Chris